# Why are VW units not producing a centering result on a container?

Tags: css

I'm creating a portfolio site for myself, and I want to use no outside UI libraries for this. I wanted to make a "container" where there was 2.5vw margin on the left and right edges of the page. The inner content would have a width of 95vw. When tested at 800px, the inner content does have a width of 760px. But the left margin appears to be somewhere between 4-4.5vw, and the right margin 0.5-1vw. The only margin that Chrome Inspector shows is 20px for each side, which is not true.

I've tried setting the entire body width to 95vw and margin: 0 2.5vw. I've also tried taking out the navbar width, adjusting it's position (Not sure why I tested this, as I want it for the entire site). I've opened the file on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, each with the same result.

Here is the HTML with the first few lines.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="top-nav">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

And the CSS accompanying it.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 95vw;
  margin: 0 2.5vw;
}

.top-nav {
  background: green;
  opacity: 0.1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 2.5vw;
  width: 95vw;
}
```

I expected 2.5vw(left-margin) 95vw(width) 2.5vw(right-margin), but am getting closer to 4.5vw(left-margin), 95vw(width), 0.5vw(right-margin). For what it's worth, converting to percentages does work, but I would like to use the same unit as much as possible.

Comment: Why not just use `margin: 0 auto`?

Comment: This could be a solution, as I don't need to specify another unit yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your styles seem to work ok.

Probably you have some problem in another style that you haven't posted

See you code working:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 95vw;
  margin: 0 2.5vw;
  height: 50px;
}

.top-nav {
  background: green;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 2.5vw;
  width: 95vw;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="top-nav">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
          </div>
```